# Taking long time to give output

Tags: plotting

Following code does not give any output. I kept it running for nearly 6 hours does but it does not give the output. What is the wrong with that?

```
a = 40.397;
b = 0.525;
c = 0.015000098827516313;
d = 0.000000001;
δ = 0.0095;
σ = 0.020

g2 = Plot[Convolve[Re[Erfc[(δ + I*x)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)]/ E^((x - I*δ)^2/(2*σ^2))], 
      a*UnitStep[x - b]*c* Sqrt[x - b]*
         ((Pi*(Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b])*Exp[Pi*(Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b])])/
       Sinh[Pi*(Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b])]) + 
      a*d*Sum[((4*Pi)/n^3)*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}],  x, y], 
      {y, 0, 1.4}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I changed. Is it clear?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
a = 40.397;
b = 0.525;
c = 0.015000098827516313;
d = 0.000000001;
δ = 0.0095;
σ = 0.020;
f = Convolve[Re[Erfc[(δ + I*x)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)]/E^((x - I*δ)^2/(2*σ^2))], 
 a*UnitStep[x - b]*c*Sqrt[x - b]*((Pi*(Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b])*
 Exp[Pi*(Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b])])/Sinh[Pi*(Sqrt[d]/Sqrt[x - b])]) + 
 a*d*Sum[((4*Pi)/n^3)*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}], x, y];
g2 = Plot[f, {y, 0, 1.4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

which appears to finish in about a minute.

Please check this very carefully to make certain that it is correct.

Comment: You could also wrap `Evaluate[]` around your `Convolve[...]` and get about the same speedup. Either precomputing `f` or using `Evaluate` will do most of the calculation once and then let `Plot` use that result, instead of having `Plot` repeat most or all of the `Convolve` calculation again and again for every one of  hundreds or thousands of points.

Comment: Thank you very much